# Tabs do not show when using PushViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller, uitabview

I'm trying to use the following code to display a tabbarcontroller

```
UITabBarController *tc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarcontroller"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tc animated:YES];
```

It does load the view, and I can tell it which of the tabs I want it to default to.  The problem is the tabs don't show.  From what I've read I gather it has something to do with putting the tab controller inside of the navigation controller, but I couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: here's a few dummy questions, is the identfyer correct? is the navigationController nil? are you using a storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Storyboard, use pushViewController method is a bad choice (also if it work). You have to insert a "*segue*".
Go in the storyboard and **while press ctrl button, click on the main controller** (which must open the tabViewController) **and then release the click on the tabBarController**.

Now you have the segue. Click on the **circle** which appears and choose an identifier for this segue, for example: **MainToTab** .

[image]

Now in your method, you have just to call:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MainToTab" sender:self];
```

Moreover, if you want manage the property on the destination controller (by segue), you can implement this method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MainToTab"]) {
        UITabViewController *tb = (UITabViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //set the properties...
    }

}
```

This method is called automatically when you launch the previous method.

Comment: The segue works perfectly when doing this, but I have a tabbarcontroller that I need to be able to load from multiple locations.

Comment: Ok, well you have to push yes..
Your code is correct. You must be secure that the identifier is correct. The tabViewController is showed?

Comment: I decided to restructure it and do away with the tabbarcontroller.

Comment: ahahah, in effects if you need multiple tabViewController, maybe it isn't the best choice ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you want inside your `UITabBarController` are `UIViewControllers`, possibly inside a `UINavigationController`.

You shouldn't as well push a `UITabBarController`. You can see Apple's explanation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html):

> An app that uses a tab bar controller can also use navigation
>   controllers in one or more tabs. When combining these two types of
>   view controller in the same user interface, the tab bar controller
>   always acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers.
>
> The most common way to use a tab bar controller is to embed its view
>   in your app’s main window. (...)

Still you can present it modally:

> It is possible (although uncommon) to present a tab bar controller
>   modally in your app. Tab bar interfaces are normally installed in your
>   app’s main window and updated only as needed. However, you could
>   present a tab bar controller modally if the design of your interface
>   seems to warrant it. For example, to toggle from your app’s primary
>   operational mode to a completely different mode that uses a tab bar
>   interface, you could present the secondary tab bar controller modally
>   using a crossfade transition.