# Is there any way to push a vc in a storyboard in init with coder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

So I have a problem when trying to push some Viewcontrollers basically when the app loads it checks if you are already registered and if you are it sends you to a diff vc and if your not registered it sends you to a RegisterVC. It's done in storyboard and the problem is that when I put the code in viewDidLoad the pushes works but I can't see the rootviewcontroller from the storyboard but if I move the code into the init with coder I can see the viewcontroller but the push return's nil in the method that's supposed to push to a new vc, so the transition never happens.

The code looks like follows:

```
    if (emp == nil) {
        [self gotoRegisterView];
    }
    else {
        [self gotoSMWView];
    }
```

and :

```
- (void) gotoRegisterView {
    UIViewController* vc = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

- (void) gotoSMWView {
    UIViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SMWVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Please if you are using storyboard,
is better to use "segue" than push's method.

Look this my comment: [ViewControllers segue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552682/tabs-do-not-show-when-using-pushviewcontroller/19552935#19552935)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards, just connect the main scene to any other scene you want to call from there.  Then, `Ctrl+Drag` from the initial `VIEW CONTROLLER` (not elements on the view controller, but from the controller itself).  Then click on the segues you just created and give them good descriptive names.  For this example, we'll just say `segue1` and `segue2`.

Now, if `segue1` takes you to the `RegisterView`, and `segue2` to `SMWView` then you can do this:

```
- (void) gotoRegisterView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
}

- (void) gotoSMWView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];
 }
```

---

If you need to do any other initialization or set up on these view controllers, you can override this method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

---

Within this method, you can check which `segue` has been called using this template:

```
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue1"])
```

---

And you can get an instance of your destination view controller like this:

```
YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
```